# Accessing a database on a mapped drive in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I have built a SQL database program that holds part numbers and details about them. Right now the program works locally on my machine. However, what I need to do is have the program access the database on a network drive (eg. the `L:\` drive). This way, a user can have their own copy of the program, but all the data that is sent and received is done to that common networked database. I have been playing around and also searching online, but cannot seem to find anything, and I am a database beginner. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to have the  Database stored on a Server location network drives are always subject to change and what if the user already has a network drive mapped to `L:` then what do you do..?

Comment: If you need to have a *common networked database* - just set up an actual **SQL Server** (or any other database server) and connect to it using some protocol and a logical database name. Don't take file-sharing to the network for databases! That's **not** a good idea....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is install a [sql server instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545450.aspx) somewhere on your [network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx).  Then use a [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) rather than a drive location to access the data.

This is the standard way to share data across applications.

Comment: you are exactly right. I contacted my IT guy who dabbles in databases, and he got me hooked up.

Answer (score 1):

THe problem with this approach is locking and multiuser support to put it simply.  You will run into users contending for access to the file .  You need a DB server ( SQL Server , Sql Server Express, MySQL , etc etc) to handle this problem for you .    The DB server can running on that network server .